# Copying files with a specific pattern

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to copy files from one location to another and given below are some sample ones:

```
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_cost_code_20140330.gz
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_revenue_zone_20140329.gz
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_benefit_extract_20140330.csv.gz
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_profit_zone_20150509.csv.gz
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_loss_zone_20140330.csv
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_username.csv.gz
```

from the above list, the files that should be copied should be in the following format:

```
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_cost[or]revenue[or]benefit[or]profit[or]loss_yyyymmdd.csv.gz
```

which means that the files

```
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_loss_zone_20140330.csv
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_username.csv.gz
```

shouldn't be copied.

Also, I need to assign it to a variable and I am trying something like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
FILENAME="egrep 'aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_(cost|revenue|benefit|profit)_code_[0-9]{8}.csv.gz'"
```

The reason I am trying to assign this to a variable is because I need to use it later in the code for something like this:

```
SOURCE_DIR="/temp"
DESTN_DIR="/output"
FILENAME=`egrep 'aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_(cost|revenue|benefit|profit)_code_[0-9]{8}.csv.gz'`
echo "FILENAME is:" $FILENAME
for SAMPLE_FILE in $(ls "$SOURCE_DIR/$FILENAME")
do
cp $SAMPLE_FILE $DESTN_DIR
done
```

Is there an alternate way in which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 5):

Use `find` and its `-exec` option (here using GNU `find` for it's `-regex` predicate):

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_(cost|revenue|benefit|profit|loss)_[[:alpha:]]+_[0-9]+\.csv\.gz' -exec mv {} "$DESTN_DIR" \;
```

Note:

- `find .` tells `find` to look for files starting in the current directory.
- By default, GNU `find` uses emacs-style regular expressions.  I prefer `-regextype posix-egrep` but you may switch to any of the supported styles with which you are familiar.
- A regular expression is used to select the files: `-regex '.*/aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_(cost|revenue|benefit|profit|loss)_[[:alpha:]]+_[0-9]+\.csv\.gz'`.  This allows for the standard prefix of `aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_` followed by one of the words specified by `(cost|revenue|benefit|profit|loss)`, followed by another unspecified word, `_[[:alpha:]]+`, followed by a date, `_[0-9]+`, followed by the desired extension of `.csv.gz`.  You may want to fine tune this.
- Any such files found will be moved to the target directory via `-exec mv {}  "$DESTN_DIR" \;`.  When `find` finds a matching file, it executes this command replacing `{}` with the file name.  This will work even if the file names have spaces, newlines, or other difficult characters.

#### Using the default (emacs) style of regular expression

The default style of regex for GNU `find` requires some escaping of the grouping and alternation operators:

```
find . -regex '.*/aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_\(cost\|revenue\|benefit\|profit\|loss\)_[[:alpha:]]+_[0-9]+\.csv\.gz' -exec echo mv {} targetdir \;
```

#### Mac OSX

The Mac OSX version of `find` ([man page here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html)) supports `-regex` but not `-regextype`.  I wouldn't be surprised, though, if its regex syntax required some subtle changes.

#### IBM AIX 5

The man page for the IBM AIX version of `find` is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/find.htm).  It is does *not* support `-regex`.

Comment: John, I get the error -->find: 0652-017 -regextype is not a valid option. I am using this on Korn Shell

Comment: @user68112 I have added a version that doesn't use regextype.  Are you on Linux(GNU) or OSX(BSD)?  I tested both the commands above with GNU find version 4.4.2 (linux). GNU and OSX/BSD, unfortunately, often have minor but very annoying incompatibilities.

Comment: I am on AIX 5.3 and running on Korn Shell but sadly the same  issue still persists even with regex

Comment: @user68112 I found the man page for AIX `find` [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/find.htm) and, as you have found, it does not support either `-regexttype` or `-regex`.  I have updated the answer to note that.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob
source_dir="/temp"
destn_dir="/output"
pattern='aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_(cost|revenue|benefit|profit)_code_[0-9](#c8).csv.gz'
print -r "pattern is: $pattern"
cp -- $source_dir/$~pattern $destn_dir
```

ksh93 patterns can express that with

```
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_@(cost|revenue|benefit|profit)_code_{8}(\d).csv.gz
```

And `ksh88` with:

```
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_@(cost|revenue|benefit|profit)_code_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv.gz
```

However the *extended* globbing operators don't work inside variables so as to avoid breaking POSIX compatibility:

```
echo @(a)
```

is wrong syntax as per POSIX, so `ksh` can make it a new glob operator. However:

```
x='@(a)'
echo $x
```

is completely specified per POSIX and is meant to output `@(a)` (with the default value of IFS), not `a` if there's a file called `a` in the current directory.

So you'd need to resort to using `eval` which can be tricky to get right

```
pattern='aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_@(cost|revenue|benefit|profit)_code_{8}([0-9]).csv.gz'
print -r "pattern is: $pattern"
eval 'cp -- "$source_dir"/'"$pattern"' "$destn_dir"'
```

Comment: what is `cp -- ..` ?

Comment: @Babyy, That's `cp $file_or_option $dest` or `cp -- $file $dest`. `--` marks the end of options. Generally, when passing variable arguments to command, you need to mark the end of the options with `--` so that the arguments are not taken as options by mistake. (note that you can leave out  quotes like that with zsh only, with other shells it's `cp -- "$file" "$dest"`, and  even with zsh, that doesn't harm to use quotes here)

Comment: @Stephane, Is there an equivalent option for ksh as well?

Answer (score 1):

That can be done in one line:

```
find /temp -maxdepth 1 -type f | \
 grep -P 'aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_(cost|revenue|benefit|profit)_.*[0-9]{8}' | \
 xargs cp -t /output
```

- `find` lists the contents of the folder without subfolders.
- `grep` your filenames
- and copy (`cp`) them of the target directory (`-t`)

You just have to ajust your regex, because in your question it was not 100% clear. Some files have `.csv.gz`, some `.csv` and some `.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

```
set -- ./aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_[!ul]*
cp "$@" -t $location2
var=$*
```

Answer (score 1):

Any modern shell supports what you want directly, not with the basic glob syntax but like this:

```
cp aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_{cost,revenue,benefit,profit,loss}_[0-9]*.csv.gz destination_dir
```

This expands into five arguments, each of which is a glob of the form `..._keyword_<digits>...`

So, to answer your second question, here's how to assign each one to a variable in turn:

```
for FNAME in aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_{cost,revenue,benefit,profit,loss}_[0-9]*.csv.gz
do
    echo $FNAME
    if [ -e $FNAME ]
    then
        cp $FNAME <destination>
    fi
done
```

The existence check (`if [ -e $FNAME ]`) is because if any of the five globs doesn't match anything, the glob will be retained as-is and you'll get an error message.

Comment: with the for loop option above, it says: A file or directory in the path name does not exist. It probably is considering it as a file and not as a pattern

Comment: Oh right, that's indeed what it is: If you use a glob and it doesn't match anything, it stays in its glob form. Does it echo the star right before the error? You can add a `if [ -e $FNAME ] then ...` to suppress the error.